# No signing identity available

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I have made an app in Xcode, and want to build my app on my own iPad. I have a paid developer account. I did the following:

- Created a development certificate in member center, downloaded it and double clicked it. It is added to keychain
- Created an app ID in member center and made sure the bundle identifier mentioned here corresponds with the bundle identifier I have in Xcode
- Registered the iPad in Devices in member center
- Created a development provisioning profile in member center, enabled the certificate I just created, referred to the app ID I just created, enabled the registered device; downloaded the pp and double clicked it

When I now in Xcode in the general build settings of my target, for my team choose my personal team (which is from the certificate I just created), and in the build settings of my project select the provisioning profile I just created, Xcode complains that there is no identity available for this profile. Which step am I forgetting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work. I was doing everything alright, but Xcode was just not cooperating. It worked after I had delete all my provisioning profiles from `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/` and install the provisioning profile that I want to use again.